# java using returned values from methods

Tags: java, string, int, return

My student grade classifier needs to use the returned values, and I have tried but the input is prompted for three times. I'm sure this is because I'm calling the method `getStudentMark()` to use the retrieved value from that method.

Code:

```
public static int getStudentMark()
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Exam Mark :> ");
    int mark = in.nextInt();

    return mark;
}

public static String getStudentFinalGrade()
{
   int studentGradeMark = getStudentMark();
   String studentGrade = "";

    int studentGradeMark = getStudentMark();
if (studentGradeMark >= 90) {
    return "A";
} else if (studentGradeMark >= 80) {
    return "B";
} else if (studentGradeMark >= 70) {
    return "C";
} else if (studentGradeMark >= 65) {
    return "D";
}
return "F";

   return studentGrade;
}


public static void printGrade()
{   
    System.out.println("Your Grade is" + getStudentFinalGrade());
}
```

Then calling these in the main method (which I cannot change):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getStudentMark();
    getStudentFinalGrade();
    printGrade();
}
```

Where am I going wrong when assigning the `int`?

It keeps asking for an input 3 times. Then works on the third attempt

Comment: Post *real* code or we can't help you.

Comment: Exactly what does *//SAME FOR REST OF CRITERIAS* mean?

Comment: so if code is less than 70 its Grade B, less than 60 Grade C etc.

Answer (score 0):

to get an input grade. Just read nextLine, use a regular expression to see it's a number and the use `Integer.parseint(String grade)` to get the final grade.

Comment: Hi there, 

Ive got the program to read an Integer value from the user just need that value to be passed on using the return statement that i have in here: public static int getStudentMark()
{
    //use scanner to get the int value
    int mark = in.nextInt()

    return mark;
}